# Как отвязать шапку от карточки товара html css

Tags: html, css

Как отвязать шапку сайта от карточки товара, они выделяются как одно, и соеденены вместе как исправить

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-Medium";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-MediumItalic";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-MediumItalic.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-Bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Bold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-BoldItalic";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-BoldItalic.ttf");
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 700vh;
}
#block-body {
    width: 1035px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    height: auto;
}
header {
   width: 1035px; 
   height: 80px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
}
<!--#22B14C-->
#block-content {
    width: 1035px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
}
.logo a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
    color:  #b2aeb2;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.use {
    color: white;
    
}
.web {
    color: #429595;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px; 
}
.logo p {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #22B14C;
}
.top-menu {
    width: 685px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 171px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:  "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #121313;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.top-menu ul li a:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #22B14C;
}
.block-top-auth {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 80px;
}

.block-top-auth p {
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    
}
.block-top-auth a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #121313;
    font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block-top-auth a:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    color: #124f2e;
}
nav ul ul .submenu-link{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}

nav ul ul li .submenu-link{
    min-width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}


/* Стили меню */ 
.submenu-link {
    display: block;
    width: 171px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #121313;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}   

.submenu-link:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #22B14C;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

.submenu-content a{
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128);
    border-bottom-width: thin;
}

a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.dropdown:hover .submenu-content {display: block;}
/*.dropdown:hover .submenu-link {background-color: #3e8e41;}*/

.fa {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.image{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.info h3 {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.info-price {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.add-to-cart {
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #8bc34a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.price {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.product {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Шапка для сайта</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

    <div id="block-body">

     <header>

     <!--// разметка для логотипа -->

       <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
          <!-- <span class="use">Вкус</span><span class="web">Няшка</span>-->
        </a>   
       <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>    
       </div>  

       <!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

       <nav class="top-menu">
         <ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
             <button class="submenu-link">Каталог<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                  <div class="submenu-content">
                      <a href="#">ОВОЩИ, ФРУКТЫ, ЯГОДЫ, ЗЕЛЕНЬ</a></li>
                      <a href="#">fdddsf</a></li> 
                      <a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
                      <a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
                      <a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
                  </div>
            </div>
             <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
         </ul>  
       </nav> 

       <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

       <div class="block-top-auth">
         <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>  
         <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>  
       </div> 


  <div class="container mt-5">
     <div class="row">
       
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="product">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
              <h3>Название ава</h3>
              <div class="info-price">
                <span class="price">256<small>₸</small></span>
                <button class="add-to-cart"><ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

     </div>
   </div> 

         
     </header>

      <div id="block-content"></div>  
        
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `container mt-5` вынеси из `header` и добавь к нему `margin-top`

Comment: не получается, можешь код написать/

Comment: У тебя структура не правильная. Тег `<ul>` устанавливает маркированный список. Каждый элемент списка должен начинаться с тега `<li>`. У тебя там див, внутри еще один див в нем закрывающие `</li>` открывающих нет.. Тэг `i` вообще не понятно зачем вставлен.. Исправь структуру и потом обязательно получится вынести `container mt-5`